# Finding the formula for the diagonal count of a regular $n$-gon using Galois Theory.

Tags: geometry, number-theory, galois-theory

Here's the explanation I gave to my teacher in 11th grade. I decided I might as well try to utilize Galois Theory in order to show it.

Find the diagonal count of any regular n sided polygon.

Suppose $p(x)=x^n-1=0$, such that $n \geq 3$. Then $p(x)$ factors as:
$x^n-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(x-\zeta_n^k\right)=(x-1)\left(x-\zeta_n\right) \ldots\left(x-\zeta_n^{n-1}\right)=0$.
This factorization implies that $x=1, \zeta_n, \ldots, \zeta_n^{n-1}$ where $\zeta_n \neq 1$. Therefore the splitting field of $x^n-1=0$ is $\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_n\right)$.

$\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n^{\text {th}}$ root of unity, meaning it generates all other roots of unity, so $\left|Aut\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_n\right) / \mathbb{Q}\right]\right|=\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ is Euler’s totient function.
Let $\sigma^k$ map $\zeta_n$ to $\zeta_n^{k}(\zeta_n)$. Then $\sigma\left(\zeta_n\right)=\zeta_n^{n+2}, \sigma^2\left(\zeta_n\right)=\zeta_n^{n+3}$, and so on. If $\zeta_n^n$ produces a shift of $360^{\circ}$ around the complex unit circle, then $\sigma\left(\zeta_n\right), \ldots, \sigma^{n-1}\left(\zeta_n\right)$ simulates a shift of $\frac{360^{\circ}}{n}$, or $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ radians.
Thus all automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_n\right)$ are symmetrical w.r.t its vertices on the complex unit circle. This implies that every respective conjugate of $\zeta_n$ lies exactly $180^{\circ}$ from each other.

Since all regular polygons are symmetrical, the action of each automorphism in Aut$\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_n\right) / \mathbb{Q}\right]$ on $\zeta_n$ forms an n-gon on the complex plain.

Now, we know that the first 2 roots of unity, one trivial and the other being primitive, are conjugate pairs of each other. Therefore we must choose two of them, which will be given by $_nC_2=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. But, we need to subtract n from it since no diagonals can be formed using adjacent vertices. Thus, $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - n$ = $\frac{n(n-1)-2n}{2}$. This implies that $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$ must be the number of diagonals of any n-sided polygon.

In conclusion, by leveraging the properties of polynomial factorization, field theory, and Galois Theory, we have derived a concise formula for the number of diagonals in any (n)-sided polygon. The expression $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$ encapsulates the count of non-adjacent vertex pairs, considering the symmetrical actions of automorphisms on the roots of unity in the complex plane. This result not only provides a mathematical representation of polygon diagonals but also showcases the elegant interplay between algebraic structures and geometric concepts.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I like your geographical metaphore of "complex plain"

Comment: @FShrike the question is to find the diagonal count of any regular n-sided polygon.

Comment: Not really, since you believe you have figured it all out already. It is entirely unclear what you expect us to do. Btw, this doesn't feel like a genuine application of Galois theory, you concluded (dubiously) that the roots of unity describe an $n$-gon which is entirely elementary